# Python Openpyxl: How to take values from a column, append it to a string and then make the new string part of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, string, openpyxl

I am using Python Openpyxl to extract values from an Excel sheet, store it into an array, and use the array to write to a new file.

This is the code;

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="./test.xlsx")

for column in sheet.iter_cols(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_row=300, max_col=1):
    for cell in column:  
        fileNameArray.append(cell.value)
```

Now, I want to create a new array called linkArray as follows;

1. If filename starts with anything but XYZ, then linkArray for that corresponding fileName in fileNameArray should be https://www.linkName.com/fileNameArrayValue1.
2. If filename starts with XYZ, then linkArray should be https://www.differentLinkIfNameStartsWithXYZ/fileNameArrayValue2.
   And so on for hundreds of values.

So, in the end;

linkArray = ['https://www.linkName.com/fileNameArrayValue1', 'https://www.differentLinkIfNameStartsWithXYZ/fileNameArrayValue2' ...]

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `values_only`.

Comment: What is blocking you? You already have the value, so just check if it `startswith` your prefix and then build one string or the other and append it to `linkArray`

Comment: @gimix Hi, any chance you can give us a sample answer? I am looking for the most efficient way because the fileNameArray will have hundreds/thousands of entries and I don't know how to get a string from there and use it as input to populate a different array.

Answer (score 1):

Extending your code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="./test.xlsx")

for column in sheet.iter_cols(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_row=300, max_col=1):
    for cell in column:
        temp = cell.value
        fileNameArray.append(temp)
        if temp.startswith('XYZ'):
            linkArray.append(f'https://www.linkName.com/{temp}')
        else:
            linkArray.append(f'https://www.differentLinkIfNameStartsWithXYZ/{temp}')
```

or, if you are populating `linkArray` in a second moment:

```
for temp in fileNameArray:
    if temp.startswith('XYZ'):
        linkArray.append(f'https://www.linkName.com/{temp}')
    else:
        linkArray.append(f'https://www.differentLinkIfNameStartsWithXYZ/{temp}')
```